# How do I automatically split an audio file where a tone occurs?

Tags: audacity, audio-processing

I have an audio recording in which 1 kHz tones divide its segments. There are so many segments that it would take a while to use Audacity to manually split the file. Is there an automatic plug-in or program to do this?

Comment: It may not be a practical suggestion, but find the binary code for that tone, and split by it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually possible using [Audacity's Beat Finder](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/beat_finder.html) analysis plug-in when combined with a bandpass filter.

1. Duplicate your mono audio track.
2. Find the tone's exact frequency.

   1. Select the tone you want Audacity to detect and choose Analyze → Plot Spectrum.
   2. Set the size to 16384.
   3. Move the mouse pointer over the highest peak.
   4. Look for the "peak" frequency.
3. Use a bandpass filter to remove everything but the tone.

   1. Select the entire tone detection track and choose Effects → Nyquist Prompt.
   2. Type `(reson s 1000 1 1)` into the box.
   3. Replace `1000` with the frequency you got from Step 2.
   4. Click OK.
4. Optionally, apply the Amplify effect, setting New Peak Amplitude to zero.
5. Use Analyze → Beat Finder. Start with Threshold Percentage equal to 100; reduce that percentage until Audacity successfully detects the tone.
6. Use File → Export Multiple to actually save the marked segments as separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how's your lisp? Audacity multi-export, as described http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Splitting_recordings_into_separate_tracks does what you want, given appropriate labels.

Seems it'd be possible to combine the auto-label-silence script from there (named SilenceMarker.ny) with the simple spectral processing example from http://audacity-forum.de/download/edgar/nyquist/nyquist-doc/examples/rbd/03-fft-tutorial.htm to do labeling based on freq. If **I** had to do it, I'd give it a try, but lisp isn't one of my languages.